# Prevent Class from updating attributes if None

Tags: python, class

I have a Device class like so, that I pass data from a websocket to.   The data from the websocket isn't always the same, so what I want to do is only update the value of each item in the class, if it is not None.

As an example, the `message_data` might be the below on the first message

```json
{
  "ssdp": "foo",
  "ip": "bar"
}
```

and then the following on the second:

```json
{
  "ssdp": "foo",
}
```

My code is below:

**Script**

```py
                if self._device is None:
                    self._device = Device(message_data)

                device = self._device.update_from_dict(message_data)
```

**Class**

```py
@dataclass
class Info:
    ssdp: str
    ip: str

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(data):
        return Info(
            ssdp=data.get('SSDP'),
            ip=data.get('ip'),
        )


class Device:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.info = None
        self.update_from_dict(data)

    def update_from_dict(self, data):
        self.info = Info.from_dict(data)
        return self
```

Unfortunately at the moment, this is returning

```
{'info': Info(ssdp='foo', ip='bar')}
```

and then

```
{'info': Info(ssdp='foo', ip=None)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never show exactly how you use your `class Device`, so I'm going to have to guess:

You create a new `Device` from data, and later you get new data and want to do an update.

This constitutes two completely different operations, and `Device` already has these two operations, but `Info` does not.

Here is my code with two methods for `Info`:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Info:
    ssdp: str
    ip: str

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(data):
        return Info(
            ssdp=data.get('ssdp'),
            ip=data.get('ip'),
        )
    def update_from_dict(self, data):
        self.ssdp = data.get('ssdp', self.ssdp)
        self.ip = data.get('ip', self.ip)


class Device:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.info = Info.from_dict(data)

    def update_from_dict(self, data):
        self.info.update_from_dict(data)
        return self
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.info)
    

d1 = {
  "ssdp": "foo",
  "ip": "bar"
}

d2 = {
  "ssdp": "test",
}

dev = Device(d1)
print(dev)
dev.update_from_dict(d2)
print(dev)
```

Output:

```
Info(ssdp='foo', ip='bar')
Info(ssdp='test', ip='bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
@dataclass
class Info:
    ssdp: str
    ip: str

    @staticmethod
    def update(data, info):
        return Info(
            ssdp=data.get('SSDP', info.ssdp),
            ip=data.get('ip', info.ip),
        )


class Device:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.info = Info(None, None)
        self.update_from_dict(data)

    def update_from_dict(self, data):
        self.info = Info.update(data, self.info)
```

This is how I would go about it. I make use of the default value to the `dict.get()` and then consequently pass the current info through to the `update` method. It is annoying that you have to initialise the info as `Info(None, None)`, but someone else might have a better approach :)

Comment: Thanks, although this presents a similar issue to above, where if the data passed to Info includes parameters that aren't defined, it errors

Answer (score 0):

Try with these redefined new classes:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields, replace
from operator import attrgetter

@dataclass
class Info:
    ssdp: str = None
    ip: str = None


class Device:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.info = Info()
        self.update_from_dict(data)

    def update_from_dict(self, data):
        keys = set(map(attrgetter('name'), fields(self.info)))
        data = {k: v for k, v in data.items() if k in keys}
        self.info = replace(self.info, **data)
        return self
```

This solution is using the [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.replace) function, which basically creates a new object of the same type as the input object, replacing fields with values from changes.

Comment: Would this work as there is now no reference to the Info dataclass?

Comment: @K20GH, yes, give it a try! Actually, you're passing `self.info` to `replace`, which is a `Info` object.

Comment: Unless im missing something, `self.info` is never declared as an `Info` object?  When I try this, it throws that error `TypeError: replace() should be called on dataclass instances`

Comment: @K20GH Oh, right, because of `self.info = None`. Can't you create an empty Info object instead?

Comment: Yep I've done that, although the issue I now have is that if the data passed to Info includes some values that have not been defined, it errors, which is why I had the `from_dict` function

Comment: @K20GH Would you try now and let me think if this is now working? I filtered out unwanted data

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this readapted version of  your code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass 

@dataclass
class Info:
    ssdp: str = None
    ip: str = None

    def from_dict(self, data):
        self.ssdp = data['ssdp'] if 'ssdp' in data.keys() else self.ssdp[0],
        self.ip = data['ip'] if 'ip'  in data.keys()  else self.ip[0],
        return self 



class Device:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.info = Info()
        self.update_from_dict(data)

    def update_from_dict(self, data):
        self.info.from_dict(data)
        return self
```

For test purposes :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    data = {
    "ssdp": "foo",
    "ip": "bar"
    }

    msg_data = {
    "ssdp": "test",
    }

    device = Device(data)
    print("before: ", device.info)

    device = device.update_from_dict(msg_data)
    print("after: ", device.info)
```

output :

```
before:  Info(ssdp=('foo',), ip=('bar',))
after:  Info(ssdp=('test',), ip=('bar',))
```